# How to inject language OR reference in intellij 15

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

In intellij 14 i had to use JSON directly added into my string. But have not seen something with intellij 15. Can someone tell me what is a shortcut for that?

Attached reference video from java zone (see video of time 26.20):
http://2015.javazone.no/details.html?talk=0802cb9274ebf62bddf5f8563d99a9a95daf0b5c8c2c39548971855882364ac8

Comment: What's happening when you press alt+enter and go 'inject language reference'??

Comment: There is no 'inject language reference' there. Only "Split into declaration and assignment"  appear when i press alt+enter

Comment: As per the [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/using-language-injections.html#d69166e5](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/using-language-injections.html), please check that the **IntelliLang** plugin has not been disabled for some reason.

Comment: I just verify this it is already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ctrl+Alt+S
2. Editor/Intentions
3. click enable the checkbox "Inject language or reference"

After that you will see "Inject language or reference" options in editor.